# Feature projection into equirectangular panorama with THREE.js

Tags: three.js

Relatively new to THREE.js. I am trying to figure out how to project a DIV with text into an equirectangular panorama.

I have this simple example working with my panorama images.
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular

The question: I have a latitude and longitude of a feature that's in my panorama, I'd like to project a DIV labeling such item into 3D space. How do I convert longitude and latitude into X and Y on the canvas so I can change the DIVS left and top style attributes so the label renders in 3D space and appears fixed to its coordinates?

UPDATE:
For clarity, how does one take planet earth longitude and latitude, and convert it into X Y pixels inside a mesh? I know where the image was taken on earth, and I know where an item in that picture was taken on earth. I want to label that item in 3D space.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code from this question seems to do the trick:
[3d coordinates to 2d screen position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395921/3d-coordinates-to-2d-screen-position)

```
function getCoordinates( element, camera ) {

    var screenVector = new THREE.Vector3();
    element.localToWorld( screenVector );

    screenVector.project( camera );

    var posx = Math.round(( screenVector.x + 1 ) * renderer.domElement.offsetWidth / 2 );
    var posy = Math.round(( 1 - screenVector.y ) * renderer.domElement.offsetHeight / 2 );

    console.log( posx, posy );
}
```

I updated the jsfiddle with the new version of Three.js

http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/409/

Comment: Thanks. However this doesn't address my question. The question is, how does one convert planet earth latitude and longitude, into pixel X Y inside a mesh. I know the latitude longitude of the center of the sphere.